# Integrate a GPS sensor with robot_localization and use move_base node

Tags: navigation, gps, move-base, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I’m trying to integrate a `GPS` sensor to my mobile robot with the `robot_localization_node`. I have an IMU sensor added to my `robot_localization_node` but now I have some theoretical questions about how to integrate the `GPS`.

I would like to use the output of the `robot_localization node` to feed the `move_base node` in order to set some waypoints in GPS coordinates (can be in UTM) and then the robot follow them.
I’m a bit lost about how to proceed. This is what I think:

I launch `ek_localization_node` with this inputs: `IMU` and `wheel_odom`. And I remap the output topic to `local_odometry`. It'll be the local odometry in odom frame. (I must use this topic to input to `move_base` if I want to navigate in `odom` frame).

Then I launch `navsat_transform_node` with `IMU`, `wheel_odom`, and `GPS NavSatFix` and the output topic in world frame is `/odometry/gps`. But this topic is publishing only when the GPS signal is received so...

I launch another `ekf_localization node` with `IMU`,`Wheel_odom` and `odom1` (`/odometry/gps` from `navsat_transform node`). The output of this node (`/odometry/filtered`) is in world frame and is what I have to put as input to `move_base`, right?
With this configuration I don’t need to use `gps_common`, right?
When I launch all, I have to call the service `set_pose` in order to give some estimation pose in UTM coordinates to /odom in base to /world, isn’t?

**UPDATE 1:**

Thanks Tom. I've taken into account all your comments and here's my `robot_localization` [launch file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7pzj248pjdxwma/robot_localiz.launch?dl=0) and my [tf tree](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tcikqswf0db1pb/frames.pdf?dl=0).

1. I feed the `move_base` odometry with the `local_odometry` returned by my first instance of `ekf_localization_node`.
2. As I've my waypoints in UTM coordinates, their should be in `utm frame`. I can't see the tf of utm frame publishing, but in the source code I see it's `/utm`.
3. I think the `global planner` of `move_base_node` needs the global frame set to the same frame of the waypoints. So It should be `/utm`, but when I launch this configuration, `move_base_node` says this:

> [ WARN] [1422876635.213009322]:
> Waiting on transform from
> summit_a/base_footprint to utm to
> become available before running
> costmap, tf error:

I understand that `move_base` can't find the tf between `utm` and `base_footprint` frames. I don't know if it can be because the tf isn't visible by `move_base_node` or I'm doing something wrong.

- (Just to test.) If I set the global frame of the `global_panner` of `move_base_node` to `summit_a/world` it reports me this:

> [ERROR] [1422873579.326459610]: The
> goal pose passed to this planner must
> be in the summit_a/world frame.  It is
> instead in the summit_a/utm frame.

- (other test) Setting the global frame of `global_planner` to `summit_a/odom`:

> [ERROR] [1422876188.622192440]: The
> goal pose passed to this planner must
> be in the summit_a/odom frame.  It is
> instead in the utm frame.

So, the `global_planner` frame of `move_base_node` needs to be consistent or the same that the frame of the goals. `/utm` in this case.

- (Another idea) Considering how `move_base_node` works, at first I thought the best way to make the integration of `GPS`, was that the world frame represent real-world coordinates (UTM) and was the father of frame `/odom`. Thus the `move_base_node` receives waypoints respect to frame world in UTM. I understand that for easy viewing in rviz and avoid the problems of continuity, `robot_localization_node` publishes the transform `utm` as son of `/odom`, but I think this can be a little problem for navigation by `move_base_node`.

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks Tom.

1. Now I get the tf between `/world` and `/utm`. The point was that `navsat_transform_node` doesn't publish the tf until the GPS signal is nonzero.
2. The topic `/odometry/gps` without `child_frame_id` defined is meaningless for my purpose,right? Because it isn’t publish constantly if the GPS signal is lost.
3. Now my waypoints are in base to the `utm` frame.
4. With which topic I must feed the `move_base` node? I think the best option is the `/odometry/filtered` topic from my second instance of `ekf_localization_node`, isn’t it? It takes into account the output of `navsat_transform_node` and therefore the GPS position.
5. I don't really understand the problem with the heading of `IMU`, I'm sorry. My `IMU` hasn’t got compass and it doesn’t provide any kind of orientation data, just the angular velocity and lineal acceleration. In the `imu0_config` param just the angular velocity in Z is set to `true` and the stimation of the heading is enough. Is that a problem if I want to integrate the `GPS`?

Any ideas, corrections or suggestions would be appreciated.

Best regards and thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202117/integrate-a-gps-sensor-with-robot_localization-and-use-move_base-node/) by [ASoriano](https://answers.ros.org/users/20687/asoriano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2015-01-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-02**:
Thanks for the update. I'll look into this and get back to you.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-03**:
Yeah, I can't make the *utm* frame the parent of *odom*, as that would conflict with any other nodes (like `amcl`) that need to publish a *map*->*odom* transform. I need to look at move_base, but in general, if you use `tf`'s transform methods, parentage shouldn't matter.

**Comment by [ASoriano](https://answers.ros.org/users/20687/asoriano/) on 2015-02-04**:
**In response to EDIT 1.** Yes, it's still true. My IMU only offers me angular velocity and linear acceleration. Maybe can I use the orientation that the GPS gives me?

Is it possible do visible the tf odom->utm?
Thanks.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-04**:
Sure, as long as it's being broadcast. Just do this:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo odom utm
```

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-04**:
Also, yes, you can use the GPS heading, but you'd have to have some logic in there to (a) make sure the heading isn't bogus, because it will be until you move, and (b), send out an IMU message with that heading in it (might want to include the roll and pitch from your *actual* IMU as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so here's your setup as I see it:

**`ekf_localization_node` instance 1**:

- Inputs: wheel odometry and IMU
- Relevant parameters: `world_frame` is set to *odom*
- Outputs: `local_odometry` and *odom*->*base_link* transform

**`ekf_localization_node` instance 2**:

- Inputs: wheel odometry, IMU, and transformed GPS data from `navsat_transform_node`
- Relevant parameters: `world_frame` is set to *map*
- Outputs: `odometry/filtered` and *map*->*odom* transform

**`navsat_transform_node`**:

- Inputs: `local_odometry` (**incorrect**, see below), IMU, and raw GPS data
- Outputs: `odometry/gps`

Additionally, you are using the second instance of ekf_localization_node because you want GPS-integrated data to be available at a faster rate.

Answers and comments:

1. Both `odom` and `map` are "world frames." When your robot starts, they have the same origin. They will diverge as you move, however.
2. As I recall, `move_base` will let you issue a goal in any frame, but will transform it into a target frame before executing the motion commands. Someone please correct me if this is wrong. If you want to issue goals in UTM coordinates, you're in luck: there's a parameter for `navsat_transform_node` named `broadcast_utm_transform`. Set it to true. (I just realized that this wasn't documented properly on the wiki. Sorry about that.) Now you should be able to issue goals in the *utm* frame.
3. It's a minor point, but your odometry input to `navsat_transform_node` should be your `odometry/filtered` data from the second instance of `ekf_localization_node`.
4. No, you don't need `gps_common` per se, but the package should be installed, as I'm using a header file from it.
5. You should have no need to use `set_pose`. The output of `navsat_transform_node` is in a world-fixed frame that is aligned with your vehicle's start position and orientation. In other words, if your robot is at (4, 2) in the *odom* frame (`ekf_localization_node` instance 1), then its position, in a perfect world, would be (4, 2) in the *map* frame (`ekf_localization_node` instance 2).
6. Make sure your IMU reports in the ENU frame, and that you know what it reads when it points to magnetic north, and then make sure you set the parameters to `navsat_transform_node` accordingly.

Hope this helps! Let me know how it goes.

**EDIT 1**: Quick question: I noticed that in your launch file, you have this:

```
  <!--My IMU doesn't have compas-->
```

Is that still true? If so, that's going to be a problem. You need an IMU that has some knowledge of its orientation relative to north (east, really, but knowing one gives the other).

**EDIT in response to update 2**: I'm afraid it's been some time since I used `move_base`. There may be someone else who's integrated it. My guess is that you want to give it your **non**-GPS-enabled instance (instance 1) of `ekf_localization_node`. Assuming `move_base` requires your current location and a goal location, then I would hope/think it's transforming the current location and goal location into whatever frame it wants to use. However, I think you'll want the position estimate that you give to `move_base` to be continuous, and your GPS position is subject to discrete jumps. If you used instance 2, then as you got nearer to the goal, your robot might suddenly change course as your GPS jumps around.

Re: the reason for needing a compass, see [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration#Details). `navsat_transform_node` first transforms GPS data into the UTM coordinate frame. The UTM coordinate frame has its X axis facing east and its Y axis facing north. East and north are, of course, fixed to earth. Now, when your robot starts out, it may be facing, say, northeast (+45 degrees above the east/X axis), and at UTM coordinate (1000, 1000). Let's say you drive forward 10 meters. You would be at UTM position (1007.07, 1007.07) in the UTM coordinates, but in your *map* (and *odom*) frame, you should be at (10, 0). The purpose of `navsat_transform_node` is to output a `nav_msgs/Odometry` message that has converted your raw GPS location into a position that is consistent with your robot's start position and orientation. In order to do that transform, I need your current heading (+45 degrees above east). The only way to get that heading is through an earth-fixed heading reference, such as from a compass/magnetometer. Otherwise, you won't know which way you're facing with respect to the UTM grid.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3